# jquery/javascript: return and if sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery/javascript problem:
I need to return the code of an html select input, but I also need to set the selected option dynamically.

```
function(data){
  return '<select class="form-control"'+
            '<option value="1"'+ if(data === 1){selected}+'>Name 1</option>'+
            '<option value="2"'+ if(data === 2){selected}+'>Name 2</option>'+
            '<option value="3">Name 3</option>'+
          '</select>';
}
```

Attention: using $(selector).val(data); AFTER the html is rendered is NOT an option (unfortunately)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put an if inside of a sting, but you could use a ternary operator.

```
function(data){
    return '<select class="form-control"'+
            '<option value="1"'+(data === 1 ? ' selected' : '')+'>Name 1</option>'+
            '<option value="2"'+(data === 2 ? ' selected' : '')+'>Name 2</option>'+
            '<option value="3">Name 3</option>'+
          '</select>';
}
```

Comment: You need to put `selected` in quotes (i.e., `' selected'`), otherwise, it will try to interpret it as a variable.

Comment: @talemyn ahh i was figuring it was a variable from outside the scope of the function, I'll change it.

Comment: Very good. Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer. Tested and working great. I upvoted all 3 answers as they provided working alternatives

Answer (score 2):

`if` statements do not evaluate to a value. You cannot embed them inside an expression this way.

Your options are to use the ternary operator, or to build your string over several statements.

```
function(data){
  var str = '<select class="form-control"'+
            '<option value="1"';

  if(data === 1){str += "selected"}

  str += '>Name 1</option>'+
            '<option value="2"';

  if(data === 2){str += "selected"}

  str += '>Name 2</option>'+
            '<option value="3">Name 3</option>'+
          '</select>';
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery in a much cleaner fashion:

```
function(data){
     return   $('<select class="form-control"'+
                '<option value="1">Name 1</option>'+
                '<option value="2">Name 2</option>'+
                '<option value="3">Name 3</option>'+
              '</select>').val(data);
}
```

EDIT: After further testing i found that converting the jquery object to html doesn't preserve the selected attribute. Alternatively, the function can return the jquery object then .appendTo the element as is.

Comment: It should be noted this will return a jQuery object instead of a string.

Comment: yes, edited although returning the jquery object can be more useful.